# My full screen bigvideo.js video works locally on all pages but once on the server stops working, what reason could this be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, fullscreen

If you go to [this site](http://www.soakstudios.com) the video as a background works on the home page but not the about or blog page. It has the exact same script code and javascript functions but for some reason the about and blog page won't show video (but will locally), only the home page. How could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with bigvideo.js. You have some other code on the page that is throwing an error before bigvideo.js runs, so it never has a chance to do its thing.

The buggy code in question is in 'jquery.imagesloaded.min.js'. The first problem is that the code to check that a given link is on the current page fails, showing that 'about.html' is the same as 'index.html'.

The second problem is that the check to make sure target exists is wrong, so you're trying to access `$target.offset().top` when `$target` is empty and therefore the result of `offset` is null. Instead, the check should be:

```
if ($target.length) {
```

If you load the page with your browser developer tools open (any browser will do), the console or debugger will give you an error message showing exactly where the problem is.